# Android's google browsers shows some elements small

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser

As title, if I accede to my site via handy, the browser google shows some element(tables and input) very small.[image: screen shot of the page]

As you can see, the table is not readable.
Here is my css file:

```
    html {
    max-width: 100%;
}
    body {
    max-width: 100%;
}
    .head  {font-size:15px;background:    min-height:100px; }
    .logo  {max-height:100px;}
    .head a,.link{font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;  font-weight: normal;  align: left;}

    .sidebar a{font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px; font-weight:normal;  align:left; } 
    .sidebar li{list-style:square;margin:0; padding:0;   float:none; align:left;}
    .sidebar a:hover, .sidebar a:focus, .head a:hover,.head a:focus,.link:hover,.link:focus{color:#018fe2;}
    .sidebar a:active .head a:active,.link:active{color:#23aeff;}
    .sidebar li:after {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
    }
    .sidebar {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute; left:8px;
    
}
.page {font-size:14px;background: #ffffff;   min-height:100px; margin-left:16%;} 
.page img{float:none; width:100%;border:1px solid;border-color:#000000;}
.PiccoleIMG img{float:none; width:50%;border:1px solid;border-color:#000000;}
.page figcaption{font-weight:bold;}
.page p {font-family: Courier New; color:#000000;align:left;}
.page table {font-family: Courier New; font-size:12px; border:1px;}
.page input {font-family: Courier New; font-size:12px;letter-spacing:2px; }
.page h3{text-decoration:underline;]
```

The elements are inside `page` and I did not use any class.The code of the table is very simple:

```
<TABLE BORDER =1>
<TR><TH>name</TH><TH>type</TH></TR>
<TR><TD>id</TD><TD>INTEGER</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>primitive</TD><TD>TEXT</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>v</TD><TD>TEXT</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>v_a</TD><TD>TEXT</TD></TR>
</TABLE><br>
```

**How can I set the table size omogeneus with the rest of the page in Google Chrome for Android?**